# How to find the polynomial form coefficients of x with the presence of exp(1/x)

Tags: python, sympy

Consider the following expression

```
from sympy import *
a,b,c,x=symbols('a,b,c,x',real=True)
expr=a+(a+(a+b)*x+c*(a+b)*x**2 )*exp(a*x/c)
```

I wanted to simplify this expression such that it's in the "almost" polynomial form, i.e.

```
a+a*exp(a*x/c) + (a+b)*exp(a*x/c)*x + c*(a+b)*exp(a*x/c)*x**2
```

where one can extract the "coefficients" of the terms of `x**n`.

```
a+a*exp(a*x/c)
(a+b)*exp(a*x/c)
c*(a+b)*exp(a*x/c)
```

Though it's not a trivial task, I suspect that there might be a simpler built in function, but did not find one.

```
expr.series(x)
```

returned a series expansion, which expanded the `exp(a*x/c)` with respect to `x` and complicated the things.

```
from sympy import poly
poly(expr,x)
```

also failed, because

```
PolynomialError: exp(a*x/c) contains an element of the set of generators.
```

I also tried

```
expr.rewrite(x)
```

which did not do anything.

How to find the polynomial form coefficients of x in this types of expression? Is there a built in function for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a list of the polynomial forms by manually collecting terms with the same power of `x` using the [`expand()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/simplification.html#expand) and [`collect()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/simplification.html#collect) functions:

```py
from sympy import symbols, exp, collect, expand

a, b, c, x = symbols('a b c x', real=True)
expr = a + (a + (a + b) * x + c * (a + b) * x**2) * exp(a * x / c)

# Expand the expression to ensure the multiplication is distributed across the terms.
expr_expanded = expand(expr)

# Collect the terms with the same power of x.
expr_collected = collect(expr_expanded, x, evaluate=False)

for power, coeff in expr_collected.items():
    print(f'x^{power}: {coeff}')
```

**Output:**

```
x^x: a*exp(a*x/c) + b*exp(a*x/c)
x^x**2: a*c*exp(a*x/c) + b*c*exp(a*x/c)
x^1: a*exp(a*x/c) + a
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is good but I want to offer a slightly different one. The usual suggested approach for getting the coefficients of a polynomial is to use `Poly.all_coeffs` e.g. like:

```
In [14]: poly(a*x**2 + b*x + c, x).all_coeffs()
Out[14]: [a, b, c]
```

The reason this did not work in your case is because your "coefficients" include non-polynomial functions of `x` like `exp(x)`:

```
In [20]: poly(expr, x)

PolynomialError: exp(a*x/c) contains an element of the set of generators.
```

However `poly` is quite happy to create *multivariate* polynomials with things like `exp(x)` and `x` just being treated as independent variables but you either need to give it a sufficient list of variables or allow it to choose all the variables itself e.g.:

```
In [15]: a, b, c, x = symbols('a b c x', real=True)
    ...: expr = a + (a + (a + b) * x + c * (a + b) * x**2) * exp(a * x / c)

In [16]: poly(expr)
Out[16]: 
Poly(x**2*a*c*(exp(a*x/c)) + x**2*b*c*(exp(a*x/c)) + x*a*(exp(a*x/c)) + x*b*(exp(a*x/c)) + a*(exp(a
*x/c)) + a, x, a, b, c, exp(a*x/c), domain='ZZ')

In [17]: poly(expr).gens
Out[17]: 
⎛             a⋅x⎞
⎜             ───⎟
⎜              c ⎟
⎝x, a, b, c, ℯ   ⎠

In [18]: poly(expr, x, exp(a*x/c))
Out[18]: 
Poly((a*c + b*c)*x**2*(exp(a*x/c)) + (a + b)*x*(exp(a*x/c)) + a*(exp(a*x/c)) + a, x, exp(a*x/c), do
main='ZZ[a,b,c]')

In [19]: poly(expr, x, exp(a*x/c)).gens
Out[19]: 
⎛    a⋅x⎞
⎜    ───⎟
⎜     c ⎟
⎝x, ℯ   ⎠
```

The problem is that since these are multivariate polynomials the `all_coeffs` function won't work so we need to express these polynomials as univariate ones in x which we can do by "ejecting" the undesired generators:

```
In [38]: p = poly(expr)

In [39]: p
Out[39]: 
Poly(x**2*a*c*(exp(a*x/c)) + x**2*b*c*(exp(a*x/c)) + x*a*(exp(a*x/c)) + x*b*(exp(a*x/c)) + a*(exp(a
*x/c)) + a, x, a, b, c, exp(a*x/c), domain='ZZ')

In [40]: gens = [g for g in p.gens if g != x]

In [41]: print(gens)
[a, b, c, exp(a*x/c)]

In [42]: p2 = p.eject(*gens)

In [43]: p2
Out[43]: 
Poly((a*c*exp(a*x/c) + b*c*exp(a*x/c))*x**2 + (a*exp(a*x/c) + b*exp(a*x/c))*x + a*exp(a*x/c) + a, x
, domain='ZZ[a,b,c,exp(a*x/c)]')

In [44]: print(p2.all_coeffs())
[a*c*exp(a*x/c) + b*c*exp(a*x/c), a*exp(a*x/c) + b*exp(a*x/c), a*exp(a*x/c) + a]
```